# McLaurin Series Representation of $ f(x)=10^x $

Tags: calculus

I'm not sure how to represent the following function as a McLaurin series:

$$ f(x) = 10^x $$

I've attempted to calculate the first 5 derivatives of this function but it gets really messy, complicated, and error prone.Is there any easier way of doing this?

Comment: It doesn't get messy.

Comment: The first derivative I calculated is:

$$ f'(x) = (x)(10^{x-1}) $$

Comment: @Bob: The derivative of $a^{x}$ is not $xa^{x-1}$, since the exponent is not fixed - the base is. See Paul's (excellent) Notes here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DiffExpLogFcns.aspx

Comment: That's not correct. Perhaps you're thinking of the power rule $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$. But $10^x$ is not of the form $x^n$, so you can't apply that rule. Rather, as is standard, you need to write $a^x=e^{(\ln a)x}$ and use the chain rule in order to differentiate $a^x$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $10^{x} = e^{\ln(10)x}$.

Comment: How did you convert the original function into a base e function?

Comment: @Bob $e^{\ln a}=a$; the exponential and natural lograithm functions are inverse functions.